# How to set exception in the Routing Route::resource inside Route::group, in Laravel 5.7

Tags: laravel-5

I have a question about routing. I have a Route::resource inside Route::group which apply a middleware.

in the route file: route/web.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'is_admin'], function() {
  Route::resource('products', 'ProductController');
});
```

Now, I need to exclude 'index' and 'show' methods from middleware. How do I achieve that? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this,

```
Route::resource('products', 'ProductController')->except([
    'index', 'show'
]);
```

And please refer this https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/controllers#resource-controllers

Comment: I mean that to exclude 'index' and 'show' methods from middleware.  Your answer is to to generate 'index' and 'show' methods only from Route::resource. ^_^

Comment: Sorry, I mean that to exclude 'index' and 'show' methods from middleware. Your answer is to to generate all routes from Route::resource except  'index' and 'show' methods, which is nothing to do with middleware.   ^_^